# Android + robolectric test status of final class modified in asyncronous callback

Tags: android, integration-testing, robolectric

Its simply...
I want to test that when my class has finished, the callback its called and inside the callback i modified the status of my view (View.class), how can i do this with robolectric and mockito?

```
animator.addPushOutAnimationListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an activity controller with

```
ActivityController controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyAwesomeActivity.class)
```

Then you could simulate the part of the lifecycle you are interested in by invoking the right methods on the controller like this

```
controller.stop(); 
controller.destroy();
```

Then you could find the view you need and check its visibility.

Or, perhaps better, allow a way in your activity to inject (e.g. a setter) the AnimatorListenerAdapter and, in the tests, pass a mock adapter. Then you can verify that the correct method gets called on your mock.